# Data is coming twice after refreshing recyclerview

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-sliding

I'm developing an app by using **sliding tab**.After refreshing the data in         one tab and while i'm going to another tab  the text is coming twice.How to solve this problem. I'm using the adapter class.

Here is my code.

```
   mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            AsyncFetch();

            upcomingJobs.clear();
            upcomingJobs.addAll(upcomingJobs);

            // fire the event
            uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            // uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function in your adapterClass:

```
public void clearData() {
    int size = this.your_list.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.your_list.remove(0);
        }

        this.notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
    }
}
```

And then call it at the start of your

```
onRefresh()
```